# Decrypting UDP Packets from Game with Known Key

Tags: encryption, udp, wireshark, dtls

I'm trying to decrypt UDP packets for a multiplayer video game. When loading into a game session, a DTLS handshake occurs where, in Wireshark, I usually see the Client and Server agree on ChaCha20 Poly1305 encryption. The game actually live logs a "key" in a log file, which is 32 bytes long hex-coded, along with an HMAC and IV. At this point I'm not sure what to do. I tried decrypting individual messages in Python with some cryptography libraries but I realized that might be silly upon learning DTLS, or at least TLS packets, cannot be decrypted independently. I know I can possibly have Wireshark point to a file or add a key to live decrypt something, but have not had luck doing so. I started this process from basically no knowledge on internet security protocols or cryptography and have learned a lot but am at a standstill, and just want to make sure I'm not far off-base here.

[Wireshark screenshot of handshake](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V63dM.png)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the game is actually writing to the file. Wireshark has support for decrypting TLS/DTLS using the [RSA private key, the premaster secret or master secret](https://wiki.wireshark.org/TLS#tls-decryption). If the log file contains the [premaster or master secret](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5246.txt), then you should be able to shoe-horn it into wireshark, and decrypt the stream from there.

If it isn't, then you'll need to work out what it actually is first, and then it's a bit more of a manual job to get at the data.

Comment: The used ECDHE requires, that you have at least access to one of the ephemeral private ec keys in order to generate the premaster secret. So, if the premaster secret (or master secret) is not available, you will need access to one of that ephemeral private ec keys.